# Why am I generating an error when running a script in nmap on kali 2021 terminal: zsh: parse error near `\n'?

Tags: parsing, zsh, nmap

I'm getting an error every time I try to run a script in nmap on Kali 2021, I've copied it here:   zsh: parse error near `\n'  How do I resolve this? I'm a newbie so please be kind?! Syntax should be accurate so I need help.
I've copied the code with the error below:

```
nmap --script ftp-vsftpd-backdoor -p 21 <10.0.0.10>
zsh: parse error near `\n'
```

Comment: Welcome! Please check the tag descriptions when you are adding tags. `script` says don't use (!), because so generic. `n` is for a node version manager.

Comment: @Evarox : `<10.0.0.10>` means that nmap should get it's standardinput from the file 10.0.0.10 and send the standard output to the file written after the `>`. Since there us nothing written after the `>`, you get a parse error. I don't know nmap, but you probably meant `'<10.0.0.10>'` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<` and `>` are shell metacharacters; you can't use them unquoted. The intention of the example in the manpage was that you *replace* `<host>` with the hostname, not that you insert the hostname between the angle brackets:

```
nmap --script ftp-vsftpd-backdoor -p 21 10.0.0.10
```

By the way, `\n` is the character which signals the end of a line, and `zsh` is flagging an error at the end of the line because `>` must be followed by the name of the file into which the command's output will be written (probably not what you want). You might want to read an introduction to using the shell.

Comment: Thank you! I'm a dunce, I went through the manpage a few times, even nmap.org, didn't even see it.